# How to set start value for Id with strategy Increment on Doctrine MongoDB document on Symfony?

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, database

i have the following document:

```
class Purchase
{
  /**
   * @MongoDB\Id(strategy="INCREMENT")
   */
  protected $id;
...
```

I'm using this document in a Symfony 2.8.4 project.
In this case, the ID for the first document that i persist is '1', the next one will be '2' and so on.

I'd like to start the counter from 1000, but i can't figure how i can do it inside the "Model part".

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is now way to set counter in "Model part", but as the current counters are stored in the database you may alter their values there. For more details how this work you can inspect how [`IncrementGenerator::generate`](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/blob/c1e9777d1e083d819a354553522903b3b83a6f39/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/Id/IncrementGenerator.php#L53) works.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a perfect use of the [SequenceGenerator](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#sequence-generator), but not supported by the platform.

One work-around (out of the model, unfortunately) consists in setting the first ID manually.

In your controller:

```
 $object = new Purchase();
 $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager():

 $metadata = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($object));
 $metadata->setIdGeneratorType($metadata::GENERATOR_TYPE_NONE);

 $object->setId(1000);
 $em->persist($object);
 $em->flush();

 print $object->getId(); // 1000
```

Don't forget to add the setter function in your Purchase document:

```
/**
 * @param int $id
 *
 * @return Purchase
 */
public function setId($id)
{
    $this->id = $id;

    return $this;
}
```

Then, remove this logic (or wrap it in a check to verify that the object is the first being persisted).